# Comma Separated Value to Multiple BIT Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hy , I have multiple values and i need a list of checks
ex:
`1,2,4,`
`3,4,` should be :

```
day1 day2 day3 day4  
_1____1____0____1
_0____0____1____1
```

one method is

```
CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('1,', [day]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as [day1],  
CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('2,', [day]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as [day2],  
CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('3,', [day]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as [day3],  
CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('4,', [day]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as [day4]
```

please help me with a better method because i have multiple columns
thanks

Comment: Could you have 1,2,4,15000 as input?  What limits?

Comment: Here is an article about it: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows

Comment: @Chris I know I can return a table with multiple rows but I need multiple `Columns`

Comment: Ah, I misread.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string split function of your choice with pivot.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity,
  day varchar(20)
)

insert into @T values
('1,2,4,'),
('3,4,')

select isnull(P.[1], 0) as day1,
       isnull(P.[2], 0) as day2,
       isnull(P.[3], 0) as day3,
       isnull(P.[4], 0) as day4
from 
  (
  select T.ID, S.s, 1 as x
  from @T as T
    cross apply dbo.Split(',', T.day) as S
  ) as T
pivot (min(T.x) for T.s in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as p
```

Result:

```
day1  day2  day3  day4
1     1     0     1
0     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split function outlined [here](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) and then pivot the values into columns.

OR!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/sql-server-2008-how-to-split-a-comma-seperated-value-to-columns) answer looks like the same thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second table to store valid days and then query on it. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4915a/1).

**EDIT**
See updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39889/9), or code below:

```
create table test (day1 varchar(8), day2 varchar(8), day3 varchar(8), day4 varchar(8));
insert into test (day1, day2, day3, day4) values ('day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4');

create table valid_days (valid_day_no int);
insert into valid_days values (1), (2), (4);

select cast (case when exists(select 1 from valid_days where valid_day_no = substring(day1, 4, len(day1))) then 1 else 0 end as bit) day1,
       cast (case when exists(select 1 from valid_days where valid_day_no = substring(day2, 4, len(day2))) then 1 else 0 end as bit) day2,
       cast (case when exists(select 1 from valid_days where valid_day_no = substring(day3, 4, len(day3))) then 1 else 0 end as bit) day3,
       cast (case when exists(select 1 from valid_days where valid_day_no = substring(day1, 4, len(day4))) then 1 else 0 end as bit) day4
from test;
```

Note that SQL is a fixed column language, you need to use a programming language to dynamically build variable length column queries.

Comment: ('day1'), ('day2'), ('day3'), ('day4'); these should be `COLUMNS`